# Is there a way to save a reassembled TCP in Wireshark

Tags: http, tcp, wireshark, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

I am trying so sniff a multi-part POST request using Wireshark. When viewing the capture I can select "Reassembled TCP" which looks to contain the header and all the data in the transmission. However I can't seem to select the entire thing to save it. If I go back to the frame view i can select the frame, which usually selects the entire transmission, but it will only end up saving the post data.

How can I save the entire Reassembled TCP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, really simple one. There is a heading after "Transmission Control Protocol (TCP)" and "Hypertext Transfer Protocol" called "[Reassembled TCP Segments]" Selecting that allows you to save the Reassembled TCP Segments. Note to self to widen my focus a little.

Answer (score 2):

Use the "Follow TCP stream" option:
http://linuxonly.nl/docs/38/117_Wireshark.html

Answer (score 1):

Works for HTTP, DICOM or SMB streams only but there is a "[Export Objects](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChIOExportSection.html)" option now.

You can access it from `File` -> `Export Objects` -> `HTTP`.

[image: The "Export Objects" dialog box]